# Differences between `copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) ` and `copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src)`

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to learn Java Generics wildcard by reading the following:
http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103

There is one example in the material:

```
public class Collections { 
  public static <T> void copy (List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
      for (int i=0; i<src.size(); i++) 
        dest.set(i,src.get(i)); 
  } 
}
```

I was wondering if I can change the method signature as the following:

```
  public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
```

↓

```
  public static <T> void copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
```

Are there any differences between these two method sinatures?

Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Found a great explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java/4343547#4343547

Comment: @DzmitryPaulenka Thanks for your help,  but I am still not sure the differences between `List<T>` and `List<? extends T>` in this case. I think `List<T>` works just like `List<? extends>`.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct. In this case the two parameter's Type Arguments are being used to express the relationship that `dest` must contain objects of a super type of the objects in `src`. Therefore if you say `src` contains `<? extends T>` then it's sufficient to say that `dest` contains objects of T.

You can also express it the other way round, namely:

```
List<? super T> dest, List<T> src
```

to the same effect.

EDIT: I suspect the author to reinforce the point about the [PECS principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Comment: Not only for "symmetry", but also for undelining the [PECS principle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) (I don't like the description of this "PECS" thing, as in its short form, it is simply ambiguous and maybe misleading, but with a detailed description, the key point should become clear)

Comment: In this particular case, I think the PECS principle has created an overdesign of the API because it has caused more confusion. The super keyword is not needed for destination.

Answer (score 5):

As [matt freake pointed out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990441/3182664), there is not much practical difference between

```
public static <T> void copyA(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) // and
public static <T> void copyB(List<        T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

The snippet below contains an `exampleShowingThatTheyAreBasicallyEquivalent`.

The reason of why the authors chose to use `? super T` is most likely that they wanted to emphasize the [PECS principle: Producer `extends` - Consumer `super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

In this example, the first list is a **consumer** of objects. It only receives objects from the other list. Therefore, its type should be `List<? super T>`.

However, the snippet below also contains an `exampleShowingOneSubtleDifference`.I can hardly think of a case where this is really practically *relevant*, but just to point it out: When you circumvent the type inference, and pin the type `<T>` to one particular type, you can still pass in a `List<? super T>` as the first argument to the first method. In the second one, the type has to match exactly - but this is simply what the method signature says, so maybe it's obvious...

```
import java.util.List;

public class PecsExample
{
    public static void exampleShowingOneSubtleDifference()
    {
        List<? super Number> superNumbers = null;
        List<Number> numbers = null;

        PecsExample.<Number>copyA(superNumbers, numbers); // Works
        //PecsExample.<Number>copyB(superNumbers, numbers); // Does not work
    }

    public static void exampleShowingThatTheyAreBasicallyEquivalent()
    {
        List<? super Object> superObjects = null;
        List<? super Number> superNumbers = null;
        List<? super Integer> superIntegers = null;

        List<Object> objects = null;
        List<Number> numbers = null;
        List<Integer> integers = null;

        List<? extends Object> extendsObjects = null;
        List<? extends Number> extendsNumbers = null;
        List<? extends Integer> extendsIntegers = null;

        copyA(objects, objects);
        copyA(objects, numbers);
        copyA(objects, integers);
        copyA(numbers, numbers);
        copyA(numbers, integers);
        copyA(integers, integers);

        copyA(superObjects, objects);
        copyA(superObjects, numbers);
        copyA(superObjects, integers);
        copyA(superNumbers, numbers);
        copyA(superNumbers, integers);
        copyA(superIntegers, integers);

        copyA(objects, extendsObjects);
        copyA(objects, extendsNumbers);
        copyA(objects, extendsIntegers);
        copyA(numbers, extendsNumbers);
        copyA(numbers, extendsIntegers);
        copyA(integers, extendsIntegers);

        copyB(objects, objects);
        copyB(objects, numbers);
        copyB(objects, integers);
        copyB(numbers, numbers);
        copyB(numbers, integers);
        copyB(integers, integers);

        copyB(superObjects, objects);
        copyB(superObjects, numbers);
        copyB(superObjects, integers);
        copyB(superNumbers, numbers);
        copyB(superNumbers, integers);
        copyB(superIntegers, integers);

        copyB(objects, extendsObjects);
        copyB(objects, extendsNumbers);
        copyB(objects, extendsIntegers);
        copyB(numbers, extendsNumbers);
        copyB(numbers, extendsIntegers);
        copyB(integers, extendsIntegers);
    }

    public static <T> void copyA(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
        {
            dest.set(i, src.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static <T> void copyB(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++)
        {
            dest.set(i, src.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples. They are very helpful.