# On Java generics lower bound usage: ? super T

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand the usage of lower bound wildcards in some depth. I am trying to write a generic method `copy` which copies the contents of one `List` to another. I came up with this method signature:

```
<T> void copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

I think this signature is comprehensive to address all scenarios. However, I see that in the Java Collections class the method signature is like this:

```
<T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

I do not understand why they use `List<? super T> dest` instead of just `List<T> dest`. Is there some extra flexibility with their signature?

Comment: You can surround inline code with backticks in order to avoid HTML eating your generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

The following snippet passes compilation with the signature `<T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)` but doesn't work with the signature `<T> void copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src)`:

```
YourClass obj = new YourClass ();
List<HashMap<String,String>> lhm = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String,String>> lm = new ArrayList<>();
obj.<HashMap<String,String>>copy (lm,lhm);
```

Comment: The above code snippet passes compilation with both the signatures. Just checked it in Eclipse.

Comment: @user496934 Strange. I also tested this on Eclipse, and got `The parameterized method <HashMap<String,String>>copy(List<HashMap<String,String>>, List<? extends HashMap<String,String>>) of type YourClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<Map<String,String>>, List<HashMap<String,String>>)`

Comment: @user496934 Did you make the call `obj.<HashMap<String,String>>copy (lm,lhm);` or just `obj.copy (lm,lhm);`?

Comment: My bad, I just made call to obj.copy, Git it now, Thanks.

Comment: It's easy to concoct an example like this, but it's completely unrealistic. I'm still curious what practical use there is.

Comment: But this is just because you are specifying an explicit type witness, which is not the right type witness for one of the cases. That doesn't disprove the claim that the two declarations accept the same possible sets of arguments when not using type witnesses.

Comment: An explanation would have been helpfull instead of just providing an example.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no practical difference without explicit type witnesses.**

Without specifying a type witness as done by Eran, there are no differences in flexibility between the two methods.

Essentially, the use of `? super T` over `T` is only a stylistic difference, however it is better practice, as can be seen by applying a number of principles of good code:

- Explicit intent: `? super T` more explicitly shows what types `dest` should take.
- [Modularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming): you don't need to look at the type constraints on `src` at all to know what types `dest` can take.
- [Producer Extends, Consumer Super (PECS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super): a producer parameter ("in" below) should use `extends` while a consumer parameter ("out" below) should use the `super` keyword.

Using `? super T` is also recommended by the [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) (they even use a `copy` function):

> For purposes of this discussion, it is helpful to think of variables as providing one of two functions:
>
> **An "In" Variable**
>   An "in" variable serves up data to the code. Imagine a `copy` method with two arguments: `copy(src, dest)`. The `src` argument provides the data to be copied, so it is the "in" parameter.
>
> **An "Out" Variable**
>   An "out" variable holds data for use elsewhere. In the `copy` example, `copy(src, dest)`, the `dest` argument accepts data, so it is the "out" parameter.
>
> You can use the "in" and "out" principle when deciding whether to use a wildcard and what type of wildcard is appropriate. The following list provides the guidelines to follow:
>
> **Wildcard Guidelines:**
>
> - An "in" variable is defined with an upper bounded wildcard, using the
>     `extends` keyword.
> - An "out" variable is defined with a lower bounded
>     wildcard, using the `super` keyword.

Comment: This question was [also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985220/differences-between-copylist-super-t-dest-list-extends-t-src-and-co). I think the example showing all the cases in which they are equivalent is especially convincing. (Can't close as dupe because of bounty.)

Comment: @River:  It'd probably be better to flag this with a mod flag explaining that it's a dupe instead of answering it.

Comment: @Makoto found the duplicate a bit later on