# Collections.copy(..) - why is super used?

Tags: java, generics, collections

The method definition of Collections.copy(..) is as follows

`public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)`

Is there any reason for the use of using super in destination? I understand that `? super T` means unknown element which is super type of T, but to me this seems redundant in the copy.

Why not simply do the following ? It does the same thing.

`public static <T> void copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src)`

Which case is this simple method definition NOT satisfying ?

I understand the PECS rule but I want to understand which concrete example DOES NOT work for the simpler definition I just created. As far as I can see and tried experimenting, when the copy method is called - the compiler will choose the proper "T" and in every case elements would be able to be copied to dest.

***If I am wrong, I would appreciate if you can provide me a case which does not work for the simpler definition but works for the actual definition.***

Thanks !

I found that this question is answered in [Differences between `copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) ` and `copy(List<T> dest, List<? extends T> src)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985220/differences-between-copylist-super-t-dest-list-extends-t-src-and-co/34990441#34990441)